# Necessary information a topological optimisation solver needs to collect from a pre-processed CAD model

Tags: finite-element, optimization, mesh-generation

I am developing a solver that gets a CAD model as entry and does the topological optimisation calculation on it. My solver is inspired by the open-source codes presented in the literature.

Since it is just a solver I need to do the pre-processing and post-processing using a third-party code. I create my geometry and mesh using Abaqus and my solver retrieves the information in the `.inp` file in order to launch the calculation.

Currently, the information that my solver retrieves are as follows:

- The coordinate of the nodes
- element types
- Material type
- B.C., etc.

I am wondering what indispensable information any finite element code needs to retrieve from the CAD model and what information is dependent on the type of calculation and can be ignored from one simulation to the other?

Comment: can you clarify, if you mean the information from the resultant **mesh** or the **CAD model** itself?

Comment: @AntonMenshov The information from the pre-processed model. The definition of a CAD model can be extended to : "a model representing the geometry, B.C., forces, mesh".